# Writing conditional math equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, text

[image]

Hi, I want to write this equation in latex. I've write the following lines but there is no space between "j" and "and". Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks.

```
  \begin{align}
    Y_{ij} = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        \sum_{k \sim i}y_{ij}, & \text{if } i = j,\\
        {-y_{ij}}, & \text{if } i \ne j   \text{and } i \sim j,\\
        0, & \text{otherwise.}
        \end{array}
  \end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Write `\text{ and }`, not `\text{and }`. An observation: you have the `cases` environment which is simpler to type than `\left\{\begin{array}{lr}...`

Comment: You're missing the `\right.` to close the `\left\{`. I agreed with @Bernard, the `cases` environment would be simplier.

Answer (score 9):

You can have a simpler typing with the `dcases*` environment from `mathtools`: The `d` in the name of the environment means it will typed in `\displaystyle` and the star  means the second column will be in text mode:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
...........
 \begin{align}
    Y_{ij} = \begin{dcases*}
        \sum_{k \sim i}y_{ij}, & if $ i = j $,\\
        {-y_{ij}}, & if $ i \ne j $ and $ i \sim j $,\\
        0, & otherwise. 
        \end{dcases*}
  \end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `cases*` environment from `mathtools` package which loads `amsmath` internally. It enables you to write in normal mode in the right column, so you don't worry about spacing between words.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Y_{ij} = \begin{cases*}
  \sum_{k\sim i}y_{ij}, & if $i = j$,\\
  -y_{ij},              & if $i \ne j$ and $i \sim j$,\\
  0,                    & otherwise.
\end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding one space should do the job, as well as a few other modifications.

```
\begin{align}
    Y_{ij} = \Bigg\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
        \sum_{k \sim i}y_{ij}, & \text{if } i = j,\\
        -y_{ij}, & \text{if } i \ne j \text{ and } i \sim j,\\
        0, & \text{otherwise.}
        \end{array}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Writing `\\text` instead of `\text` cannot be correct; did you maybe intend to suggest replacing `\text{and }` with `\text{ and }`? To make your code compilable, it's necessary to add a `\right.` statement after `\end{array}`. (The OP's code lacks the `\right.` statement as well.) Furthermore, you may want to change the column specification from `lr` to `ll`, get rid of the unnecessary curly braces around `-y_{ij}`, and use an `equation` environment instead of an `align` environment.

Comment: ...now there's an additional space after `and` (one inside the `\text` and the other a control space `\ `). Additionally, the left brace is too small compared to the 3-line construction. It's better to use `cases` (or similar here).